# Spin Constancy During Transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If you impose an external B field, with components x, y, z given as (0,B,0), on a free electron, this may produce precession of the y spin axis and I generally follow the simple Hamilition structure behind this result.

But, in an earlier question I learned that, for bound states at least, electric dipole transitions don't change the spin of a particle, which I assumed they could (because I was incorrectly thinking classically).

Is this uchanged spin of the electron during transitions due to the fact that we can treat the proton (ignoring quark structure in this case), and electron as point particles, so that their E and B fields can essentially be viewed as constant / non interacting (w.r.t spin)  and therefore no electron spin changes occur during transitions?

A simple yes or no answer is (obviously I hope, if I am correct) sufficient for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [selection rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule) have nothing to do with the idea of treating anything as point particles or any fields as constant, but are derived from certain symmetries of the transition moment, essentially.

In fact, the selection rule $\Delta S = 0$ is *not* strict, but violated in the case of so-called *intermediate coupling*, where neither the separate treatment of $L$ and $S$ nor the $LS$-coupling scheme are fully applicable.

Comment: My main source for q.m. practice is Squires, (problems seem excellent), which is quite a short book, but full of information to newbies.  I have only started it and not read on to the selection rules section as yet. I appreciate more and more that doing the maths reduces the need for physical visualisation, but my current knowledge of q.m and qft is extremely patchy.

Comment: a much appreciated answer, thank you. I think I can follow Squires enough to appreciate the subtlety and implications of your answer and apply them to the next question that comes up.